# how to make a thread-safe global counter in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm creating a `threading.Timer(2,work)` run threads. Inside each work function, upon some condition the global counter must increment without conflict for access of counter variable among the spawned work threads.

I've tried `Queue.Queue` assigned counter as well as `threading.Lock()`. Which is a best way to implement thread-safe global increment variable.

Previously someone asked question here: [Python threading. How do I lock a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525185/python-threading-how-do-i-lock-a-thread)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Not sure if you have tried this specific syntax already, but for me this has always worked well:

Define a global lock:

```
import threading
threadLock = threading.Lock()
```

and then you have to acquire and release the lock every time you increase your counter in your individual threads:

```
with threadLock:
    global_counter += 1
```

Comment: In Python 3, you can use `Lock` (and `RLock`, and any `threading` class instance) as `with` context. The code is a lot more readable.

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppαℭacilhας Also in Python2, and it makes it exception-safe, so I edited it.

Comment: Is there any *lock-free* threadsafe way to store and increment an integer on macOS/Arm? I found [atomics](https://github.com/doodspav/atomics) which looked great but it seems dead and won't run on Apple Silicon Macs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CPython<sup>1</sup>, you can do this without explicit locks:

```py
import itertools

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._incs = itertools.count()
        self._accesses = itertools.count()

    def increment(self):
        next(self._incs)

    def value(self):
        return next(self._incs) - next(self._accesses)

my_global_counter = Counter()
```

We need two counters: one to count increments and one to count accesses of `value()`. This is because `itertools.count` does not provide a way to access the *current* value, only the *next* value. So we need to "undo" the increments we incur just by asking for the value.

This is threadsafe because `itertools.count.__next__()` is atomic in CPython (thanks, GIL!) and we don't persist the difference.

Note that if `value()` is accessed in parallel, the exact number may not be perfectly stable or strictly monotonically increasing. It could be plus or minus a margin proportional to the number of threads accessing. In theory, `self._incs` could be updated first in one thread while `self._accesses` is updated first in another thread. But overall the system will never lose any data due to unguarded writes; it will always settle to the correct value.

<sup>1</sup> Not all Python is CPython, but a lot (most?) is.

<sup>2</sup> Credit to https://julien.danjou.info/atomic-lock-free-counters-in-python/ for the initial idea to use `itertools.count` to increment and a second access counter to correct. They stopped just short of removing all locks.