# Python - Merge data from multiple thread instances

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently working on a project that involves connecting two devices to a python script, retrieving data from them and outputting the data.

Code outline:

•   Scans for paired devices

•   Paired device found creates thread instance (Two devices connected = two thread instances )

•   Data is printed within the thread i.e. each instance has a separate 
bundle of data

Basically when two devices are connected two instances of my thread class is created. Each thread instance returns a different bundle of data.

My question is: Is there a way I can combine the two bundles of data into one bundle of data?

Any help on this is appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks for giving a code overview, but I think a MCVCE would help as well.

Comment: You can put data from both threads in a single structure (like list) with two conditions: do it with relative small chunks and use [locks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525185/python-threading-how-do-i-lock-a-thread) for access to the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using the `threading` module.

### Threading in Python

Python is not multithreaded for CPU activity. The interpreter still uses a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) for most operations and therefore linearizing operations in a python script. Threading is good to do IO however, as other threads can be woken up while a thread waits for IO.

### Idea

Because of the GIL we can just use a standard list to combine our data. The idea is to pass the same list or dictionary to every Thread we create using the `args` parameter. See [pydoc for threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Our simple implementation uses two Threads to show how it can be done. In real-world applications you probably use a Thread group or something similar..

### Implementation

```
def worker(data):
    # retrieve data from device
    data.append(1)
    data.append(2)
l = []
# Let's pass our list to the target via args.
a = Thread(target=worker, args=(l,))
b = Thread(target=worker, args=(l,))
# Start our threads
a.start()
b.start()
# Join them and print result
a.join()
b.join()
print(l)
```

### Further thoughts

If you want to be 100% correct and don't rely on the GIL to linearize access to your list, you can use a simple mutex to lock and unlock or use the [Queue module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) which implements correct locking.

Depending on the nature of the data a dictionary might be more convenient to join data by certain keys.

### Other considerations

Threads should be carefully considered. Alternatives such as `asyncio`, etc might be better suited.

Comment: An implementation of "Further thoughts" described here could make use of a `Queue` (from Queue module). It implements the necessary locking to be thread-safe.

Comment: This works great, thank you. When I added this to my code it combined all the data from both device however it did not print until I interrupted the script. How should I go about printing the data when there is new data to send?

Comment: You could have a 3rd thread that consumes the queue/list and prints it. Depending on the data maybe printing inside the thread is still feasible? Another approach some python people are using is using multiprocess to spawn a process that handles the devices and another that continues reading and computing. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html.

Comment: How about multi-threading the data into a database and retrieve it from there? All of a sudden the input is decoupled from the output. Yes, this assumes a DB capable of handling multiple connections at once, but those aren't exactly rare. Most of them are built for it.

Answer (score 0):

My general advice: Avoid using any of these things

- avoid threads
- avoid the multiprocessing module in Python
- avoid the futures module in Python.

Use a tool like http://python-rq.org/

Benefit:

- You need to define the input- and output data well, since only serializable data can be passed around
- You have distinct interpreters.
- No dead locks
- Easier to debug.